# Show progress bar until data get placed in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar, adapter

I am working with `Firebase` and `RecyclerView`in a project. Here i get some data from firebase into an adapter and show them in a RecyclerView. it is working fine, but as it takes time to get the data from firebase. So i used a progress bar which is visible until the data get retrieve from firebase. But here is a problem that it is not visible when the data is setting up in their place in adapter.

> Here is a  [**Video**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iWbO.jpg)  on this

And the code is here

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_messenger)
            progress_circular_chat.visibility = VISIBLE          // here it goes visible
            nested_sv_chat.visibility = GONE
            retrieveChatList()
    }


private fun retrieveChatList() {
             usersChatList = ArrayList()
    val userRef = dbRef.child("ChatList").child(currentUserID)
    userRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
    {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
        {
            (usersChatList as ArrayList<String>).clear()
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (dataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val userUid = dataSnapshot.key
                    if (userUid != null) {
                        (usersChatList as ArrayList<String>).add(userUid)
                    }
                }
                readChatList()
            }
            retrieveGroupChatList()
        }
    })
   }


private fun readChatList() {
        mUsers = ArrayList()
        val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
        userRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                    mUsers?.clear()
                    for (documentSnapshot in queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        val user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
                        for (id in usersChatList!!){
                            if (user.getUid() == id){
                                (mUsers as ArrayList<User>).add(user)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    chatListAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    chatListAdapter = ChatListAdapter(this, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true)
                    recyclerViewChatList.adapter = chatListAdapter
                  
                }.addOnFailureListener { e -> }
    }


private fun retrieveGroupChatList() {
          //same code as readChatList for group chats
          progress_circular_chat.visibility = GONE  // here it goes invisible
          nested_sv_chat.visibility = VISIBLE
    }
```

Here is the xml code

```
 <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_circular_chat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:progressTint="@color/button_color"/>
    
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_sv_chat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_chatList_group"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_chatList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set your `ProgressBar` visibility to `VISIBLE` at the same time set your `RecyclerView` visibility to `GONE`. Then when the loading is finished just set `ProgressBar` visibility to `GONE` and `RecyclerView` visibility to `VISIBLE`.

The way you are doing this, even though I don't see your XML code, it's you are just showing your progress bar but it is not visible because of your RecyclerView. When data is loaded, there is a slight state refresh from RecyclerView which allows ProgressBar to be visible for a second but it's gone again.

**EDIT:**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_messenger)
            progress_circular_chat.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recyclerViewChatList.visibility = View.GONE //THIS LINE IS ADDED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            readChatList()
    }    

private fun readChatList() {
        mUsers = ArrayList()
        val userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")
        userRef.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                    mUsers?.clear()
                    for (documentSnapshot in queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        val user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User::class.java)
                        for (id in usersChatList!!){
                            if (user.getUid() == id){
                                (mUsers as ArrayList<User>).add(user)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    chatListAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    chatListAdapter = ChatListAdapter(this, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true)
                    recyclerViewChatList.adapter = chatListAdapter
                    progress_circular_chat.visibility = View.GONE 
                    recyclerViewChatList.visibility = View.VISIBLE //THIS LINE IS ADDED !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    progress_circular_chat.visibility = View.GONE 
                }
    }
```

Comment: Hey @sloth i have just tried what you have suggested but it did not work.

Comment: Can you describe how it didn't work? What happened?

Comment: i have Updated my code to it's full please check it

Comment: I edited my answer, there are two lines and comments "THIS LINE IS ADDED", add those lines in your code

Comment: i've tried it again you can see the code i edited it but the result is same no  difference.

Comment: This is because you have two recycler lists. Try to hide them both.

Comment: look at the question they both are hidden.

Comment: Do you ever call retrieveGroupChatList?

Comment: Yes i have mentioned it in question.

Comment: I can see that you are calling readChatList() but I don't see calling that function. Anyway, if you are setting the visibility of progressBar and recycler view outside of Firebase listener then that's the problem. The reason is that that is an async process and it will first set visibility then go back in the listener body to fetch the data. But I can't say because I don't see the full body of retreiveGroupChatList or when it gets called.

Comment: Hey @sloth now i have added the whole code, please check it.

Comment: Okay, don't change visibility in readChatList, only do it in readGorupChatList() function. Because that's the last function you call. Also, if you are fetching data from Firebase inside readGroupChatList() also, then set visibility inside the addOnSuccessListener body, after you set your adapter and everything else. So, hide the whole layout where your recycler views are, so hide nested_sv_chat instead of each recycler view, and show progress bar in oncreate, then in readGroupChatList() hide progress bar and show nested scroll view.

Comment: it still same, no difference

Comment: Send me your whole code, from the first line in the class to the last line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228104/discussion-between-mr-groot-and-slothcoding).